# Host File Information

Tags: hosts-file

I intend to change my organization IP CLASS from CLASS A or CLASS B for 250+nodes. I need to know if I can map a single host name for 2 different IP’s in the host file.

For Example.

```
192.168.100.1 apps.abc.com
10.0.0.1 apps.abc.com
```

Thanks and I look forward to hear from you soon.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, but you won't get the round-robin effect that DNS normally provides -- once the first entry is encountered in your "hosts" file, the search [for the matching hostname] will end and this is what will be used.

Comment: +1 Though it seems that the pragmatic answer is actually "no".

Comment: @msanford:  Good point.  I chose to go with a "yes" though just in case a future version of some OS actually incorporates support for this sort of thing (that's definitely "wishful thinking" on my part, although this would be an interesting feature).